# Easiest way to center multiple objects in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Say that in PowerPoint, I have three rectangular shapes of the same size arranged horizontally next to each other and **I want to center them on a slide *as a group***. If I select all three of them and press the Align > Center button, it will align them one by one - each one of them comes to the center so in the end, they will be overlapping each other and only one of them will be visible. What I want is to keep their distribution (gaps between them) and align the group as a whole.

What I currently need to do is:

1. Select those three objects
2. Group them
3. Invoke Align > Center
4. Ungroup them

Is it possible to somehow **avoid the annoying steps two and four**? This is a very frequent operation in my case and the default behavior just doesn't do what I want to do 99% of the time. Maybe some settings or a clever macro?

BTW this is PowerPoint 2013 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Mind selecting an answer or providing your comments to the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use vertical lines on the sides of the slide.  When you want to center the three rectangles.

1. Highlight all three rectangles and the vertical lines
2. Select Distribute Horizontally
3. When the slide design is complete, delete the vertical lines.

It's more work if you only do this once, but with multiple objects it will save you time.  You can copy and paste the vertical lines to each slide to save you time as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a macro:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim shpGroup As ShapeRange
    Set shpGroup = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    shpGroup.Group
    shpGroup.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue
    shpGroup.Ungroup
End Sub
```

Select the shapes you want to do this for, hit F8, and run this macro.

`shpGroup.Group` groups the object, `shpGroup.Align msoAlignCenters, msoTrue` aligns the group to the center of the slide, and `shpGroup.Ungroup` ungroups the selected objects afterwards.

<sub>Note: There is absolutely no error handling, so you will run in to all sorts of fun errors if you select nothing, or just one shape, etc. Feel free to add in error handling if needed</sub>